# Display product category on the WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, checkout

I'm trying to add the product category to the below (working) code but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I've tried using `product_cat` but as I'm not that experienced with php, I'm just guessing how to achieve this.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_product_field_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $meta_keys = array('time','date');
    $dictionary = array('time'=>'Time:','date'=>'Date:' );
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    foreach($meta_keys as $key=>$meta_key){

        $meta_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, $meta_key, true );

        if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) $custom_items = $cart_data;

        if( !empty($meta_value) ) {
            $custom_items[] = array(
                'key'       => __( $dictionary[$meta_key] , 'woocommerce'), //or user $meta_key
                'value'     => $meta_value,
                'display'   => $meta_value,
            );
        }
    }

    return $custom_items;
}
```

Comment: @7uc1f3r The relationship between them is that I need both of them to display in the "Your Order" of the checkout page. I've managed to get the custom fields to appear with the above code and I thought that there is a way to add the product category to this, unless it's better to have seperate code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will also display the product categories on the WooCommerce checkout page

```php
function display_custom_product_field_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    // Product ID
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

    // Get post meta
    $time = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'time', true );

    // NOT empty
    if( ! empty( $time ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Time', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'   => $time,
        );
    }
    
    // Get terms
    $term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

    if( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Categories', 'woocommerce'),
            'value'   => implode( ", ", $term_names )
        );
    }
    
    // Get post meta
    $date = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'date', true );

    // NOT empty
    if( ! empty( $date ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce'), 
            'value'   => $date,
        );
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Sorry, I know I didn't specify this in my initial question but I've just realised, is there a way to change the order of how it appears in the checkout? For example, have Time, Product Category and then Date last.

Comment: `$cart_item_data` is an array that contains all the data, so you can indeed return it using a certain sorting/order method. There are many [sorting methods in PHP for arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) of which you can certainly apply one. 
You can also change the existing code so that adding the data happens in a different order. In short, it depends on your preference but it is certainly possible

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is there a quick/simple way that you could help me with using the existing code to place the category between the time and date? I don't really need a sorting system where it depends on the value, key or anything to that extent.

Comment: I updated my answer, this is in the simplest way without a special array sort function. As you asked

Comment: @ 7uc1f3r When I view this code through Dreamweaver, I'm getting a syntax error on this line `$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', ['fields' => 'names'] );`. The code still works, so should I just ignore this or is there something I need to fix?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you apply the code line in the following way? `$term_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );`